# Fake the response of a blocked XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, ajax, browser, xmlhttprequest, prototype

I am intercepting an XMLHttpRequest and preventing it from making a network call.

There are third-party scripts that I want to prevent from performing retries when the XHR doesn't respond, and therefore I'd like to mimic a response with an OK status (i.e. `readyState = 4`). Is there a way to make this happen?

```js
(function(XHR) {
  var open = XHR.prototype.open;
  var send = XHR.prototype.send;
  var abort = XHR.prototype.abort;

  XHR.prototype.open = function(method, url, async, user, pass) {
    this._url = url;
    open.call(this, method, url, async, user, pass);
  };

  XHR.prototype.send = function(data) {
    var url = this._url;

    try {
      var canSend = checkCanSend(url);
      if (!canSend) {
        // TODO respond with OK status
        this.abort();
      } else {
        send.call(this, data);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  }

  XHR.prototype.abort = function() {
    console.log('aborted ' + this._url);
    abort.call(this);
  }
})(XMLHttpRequest);
```

Comment: Here is a library for that https://github.com/pretenderjs/FakeXMLHttpRequest

Comment: I'm overwriting the XHR prototype to conditionally block requests of other production scripts, so I think this isn't quite what I'm looking for.